# javascript:focus()が効かない

Tags: javascript

以下のようなjavascriptの実装があるのですが、focus()が効いておらずフォーカスが移動しません。
因みに、focus()の対象を$('#test')のように変更した場合は正常動作しましたので、おそらくfocus対象の指定方法に間違いがあるのだと考えているのですが、どう間違えているのかがわからない状態です。

```html
$('#name').on('keydawn', function(evt) {
  var elem = evt.target;
  elem[0].children[1].children[2].children[0].focus();
  evt.preventDefault();
});
```

解決方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Comment: そのコード片だけ書かれても、それがなんなのかわかりにくいです。イベントハンドラであると書いたり、`$(..).on()` や `elem.addEventListener` を含むコードにしたり、もう少し文脈が分かるようにしてください。（実行可能なスニペットやjsfiddleもいいですが）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

つまりこういうことでしょうか・・・。

```js
$('#test').on('click', function(evt) {
  var elem = $('#test');
  elem[0].children[0].focus();
  evt.preventDefault();
});
$('#test2').on('click', function(evt) {
  var elem = evt.target;
  elem[0].children[0].focus();
  evt.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">ここをクリック（jQuery版）<textarea></textarea></div>
<div id="test2">ここをクリック（evt.target版）<textarea></textarea></div>
```

jQueryで要素を取得した前者の場合 `elem` には**jQueryオブジェクト**が入るわけですが、これは対象が一つの要素であっても、DOM要素を含んだ配列のような構造になっています。ですから生のDOM要素を使いたければ、`elem[0]` もしくは `elem.get(0)` として中身を取り出す必要があります。

一方 `evt.target` を使った後者ですが、`evt.target` には**単一のDOM要素**が入っています。配列でも、jQueryオブジェクトでもありません。ですから `elem[0]` とすると（0番目の要素がないので）undefinedになってしまいますし、既にDOM要素なのですから `elem.children[...]` とすることができます。

jQueryオブジェクトとDOMオブジェクトでは扱い方が異なります。自分が扱っているのはどちらなのかを意識して、それぞれに合わせたコードを書く必要があります。